# Is it safe to use proxies?

Tags: php, proxy, curl

i'm using php curl's proxy feature to sign in to a site. I wanna know whether this is safe or not. Can the proxy site "hack" my usename and password? I don't, actually can't, encrypt my password before sending it to the proxy server.

EDIT: 
The scenario is like this: I'm trying to scrape data from a members-only page. I sign-in with my username and password first and then scrap the data. I want to securely do this with a proxy.

thanks for ur suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sending your username and password in plain text is *never* safe, regardless of whether you use a proxy or not. Yes, the proxy can read it, and so can anyone else between you and the site you are sending it to.

Answer (score 5):

It's not safe. If you don't trust the Proxy, you shouldn't use it to transmit login data. It's absolutely possible to eavesdrop on your password, especially when it's unencrypted.